# Multiple storyboards on one property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard

I have multiple storyboards that access the same property (not at the same time). After one storyboard changed the property, the other one seems to have no access to it and does not change anything.. What can I do against this?

Sample:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" Margin="3">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush />
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="#3e8bff" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="White" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="Orange" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="White" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.Items>
        <sys:String>hey</sys:String>
        <sys:String>du</sys:String>
        <sys:String>dux</sys:String>
        <sys:String>duy</sys:String>
        <sys:String>dua</sys:String>
    </ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

This is the smallest sample code I could make. After you've hovered an item, it won't turn blue when it's selected (try to click on one item and then use the arrow keys to select items without hovering them).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the other one seems to have no access to it and does not change anything"? Do you get an error message? Specific unexpected behavior?

Comment: To be more specific, I have a ListBox. In the ItemContainerStyle I define a template for all ListBoxItems. Here I trigger IsMouseOver and IsSelected and define a Storyboard for a fade in/out effect. When the item is hovered, the background should turn orange, and when it's selected it should turn blue. I can hover one item as many times as I want, it works. But if I select it, and deselect it again, the hover effect doesn't work anymore. If I use different properties, it still works.

Comment: It seems to be something with the order of the triggers. If I put the IsSelected trigger in front of the IsMouseOver trigger (which, by the way, is a MultiTrigger and is not raised when the item IsSelected), it's the other way round: The IsSelected effect doesn't work after the item was hovered once.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have a solution!!! Triggers and actions order does matter... the answer is not to play more then one storyboard at the same time, just stop other.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="False" />
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="SelectedBegin" />
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="UnselectBegin" />
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="EnterBegin" Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseEnterSb}"/>
        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="LeaveBegin" Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseLeaveSb}"/>
        </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
    </MultiTrigger>
    <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="LeaveBegin" />
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="EnterBegin" />
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="SelectedBegin" Storyboard="{StaticResource SelectedSb}"/>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
        <Trigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="UnselectBegin" Storyboard="{StaticResource UnselectSb}"/>
        </Trigger.ExitActions>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: Wow. Pretty long time since I posted this question.. ;) Cool that you could figure it out finally!

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to reproduce your erroneous results using the following code (I'm stumped too):

```
<ListBox>
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="BorderAnimationToRed">
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="BorderAnimationToBlue">
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="Blue" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="BorderAnimationToOrange">
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="Orange" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="BorderAnimationToWhite">
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="White" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="1" Margin="3">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush />
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource BorderAnimationToOrange}"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource BorderAnimationToWhite}"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource BorderAnimationToBlue}"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource BorderAnimationToWhite}"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListBox.Items>
    <sys:String>hey</sys:String>
    <sys:String>du</sys:String>
    <sys:String>dux</sys:String>
    <sys:String>duy</sys:String>
    <sys:String>dua</sys:String>
</ListBox.Items>
```

This code is a little easier to read, as the visuals, resources, and triggers are declared separately. Maybe you could try to use EventTriggers to accomplish your goal (using the "ListBoxItem.MouseEnter" and "ListBoxItem.MouseLeave" routed events). Good luck!

Comment: I know just created the controls I want to modify twice (this was possible in my case, I just posted a simplified example). Quick + dirty..