# ListBoxItem ControlTemplete.Triggers WPF

Tags: wpf, triggers, styles, storyboard

I am applying a `ItemContainerStyle` to a `ListBox` control. In my `ListBoxItem` style I have several triggers containing storyboard animations that apply to the current state of the `ListBoxItem` (`IsSelected`, `IsMouseOver`).

It all works fine and dandy until after I have selected a `ListBoxItem`, then the `IsMouseOver` storyboard animation isn't fired for the `ListBoxItem` which was previously selected.

I can't see where the problem is, so I am hoping someone will help me out with this issue.

Cheers

Here is the code I am using

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxFeedItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="5" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid Name="Grid" Height="Auto" Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="14" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="#4CDFDFDF" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="#00DFDFDF" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="#FFDFDFDF" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetName="Bd" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="#00DFDFDF" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: unless my browser is going mental, the code is mostly missing...

Comment: I can't seem to be able to get the code to display when pasting, as in nothing appears in the preview. Had to use Pastie. Using Chrome.

Comment: Fixed. I apologise for any inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the order of your Triggers.
Have a look at [Multiple storyboards on one property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797741/multiple-storyboards-on-one-property)

Check out Yuri's answer.May be that's what you are looking for.